# regular expression replace word

Tags: python

I have a word like below

```
new_list=abcfirst|abcsecond|PAGE 1 of 1|JS 
11/25/14|abcwordsinbetweenwords|1|2|3|4|abcwordslast
```

i am trying to replace the above words like wherever PAGE 1 of 1 ( this will be varying page 1 of 2) and same for JS 11/25/14 ( this dates will be varying ) also |1|2|3|4| this with "" blanks

Expected output is:

```
abcfirst|abcsecond|abcwordsinbetweenwords|abcwordslast
```

if possible the lastword should insert after 2 | pipe symbol

```
abcfirst|abcsecond|abcwordslast|abcwordsinbetweenwords
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```py
import re
string = 'abc first|abcsecond|PAGE 1 of 1|JS 11/25/14|abcwordsinbetweenwords|1|2|3|4|abcwordslast'
lst = string.split('|')
for idx in range(len(lst)):
    lst[idx] = re.sub('PAGE [0-9] of [0-9]|JS [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]', '', lst[idx])
    lst[idx] = re.sub(' ', '<<>>', lst[idx])
lst = ' '.join(lst).split()                                 # removing blank elements from list
lst = [re.sub('<<>>', ' ', pattern) for pattern in lst]
print('|'.join(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks .. i also have one more question what if there is space in between the words like
'abc first|abc second|PAGE 1 of 1|JS 11/25/14|abcwords in betweenwords|1|2|3|4|abcwords last'

Comment: for that you need to replace that space by some special pattern. In the first for loop you can apply 4th regex like this `lst[idx] = re.sub(' ', '<<>>', lst[idx])`. Now after removing blank spaces, you can replace that special pattern with spaces again by this, I have updated my answer
`lst = [re.sub(' ', '<<>>', pattern) for pattern in lst]`

Comment: appreciated !! I did exactly the same